# Using the same version of xampp/php for frameworks and core php?

Tags: php, html, laravel, xampp, version

Can I use Xampp PHP version 7.3 for core PHP coding as well as for Laravel 7?

If there is an option of installing two versions of Xampp at the same time, I would like to know it.

Comment: Laravel is just a framework built on top of "core" PHP so yes you can use the same PHP installation for both.

Comment: Yes you can user PHP >= 7 version in Laravel and Core PHP. You have to choose and check Laravel version for php >=7.